# Read two XML files and append second XML to first XML node

Tags: xml, vbscript

I am reading an XML file like the following:

```vb
Set xml1 = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
Set xml2 = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
xml2.Async = "False"
xml1.Async = "False"

xml1.Load("file1.xml")
xml2.Load("file2.xml")

Set xml1ChildNode = xml1.selectNodes("/node")

xml1ChildNode.AppendChild(xml2)
```

Although I keep getting:

> Error: Object doesn't support this property or method: 'xml1ChildNode.appendChild'

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Get the list of nodes you want to append from file 1.
- Get the node to which you want to append from file 2.
- Loop the list of nodes obtained from file 1 and append.

Look into comments for details.

```vb
Set xml1 = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
Set xml2 = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")

xml1.Async = "False"
xml2.Async = "False"

xml1.load("C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\Desktop\\test\\file1.xml")
xml2.load("C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\Desktop\\test\\file2.xml")

'GET THE NODES TO APPEND FROM XML 1 ex:book
Set objNodeList = xml1.getElementsByTagName("book")

'GET THE NODES TO WHICH YOU WANT TO APPEND IN XML 2 ex:catalog
Set ObjectRecord = xml2.getElementsByTagName("catalog")

'LOOP THE NODES AND APPEND
For Each objNode in objNodeList
   'APPEND TO WHATEVER ELEMENT YOU WANT in xml 2 ex: first catalog element in XML 2
   ObjectRecord(0).appendChild objNode
Next

'CHECK YOUR OUTPUT
xml2.Save "C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\Desktop\\test\\file3.xml"
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple updates

- selectNodes returns a collection of nodes, so you have to iterate through it.  Use selectSingleNode to just get one.
- appendChild starts with the parent (xml2.DocumentElement or similar), and what you want to append to it.
- this actually moves the node from one document to the other.  use
  cloneNode in your appendChild if you don't want to do that.

Here's the updated code

```vb
Set xml1 = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
Set xml2 = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
xml2.Async = "False"
xml1.Async = "False"

xml1.Load("file1.xml")
xml2.Load("file2.xml")

For Each ndNode In xml1.selectNodes( "//node" )
    xml2.DocumentElement.appendChild( ndNode )
Next

WScript.Echo xml2.xml
```